# Cycles Render displays wrong UV wrapping in material mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, 3d-view

As stated, the textures do not follow the settings in the material. They seem to repeat no matter what while in material mode of the 3d-view, but render fine. Nothing in the material seems to change this. Any solution? It's not a deal breaker but it'd be more convenient if I could resolve it. This occurs on all my models, this is not a special case. Using 2.79.

In the below screenshot I am using Extend instead of repeat but this is only reflected in render.

[image]

EDIT: Apparently this is an 7-8 year old bug that's only fixed in 2.8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An alternative solution here, strangely they added the clamping options in 2.76 but those never worked in cycles material mode, and rather the workarounds people used before those options existed work perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with math so it's shown in the 3D view as well if you must:

[image]

It seems it gets a bit confusing on exact 0 and 1 on the coordinates as you can see at the edges, but if we extend the last 0.5% or so of the image it seems to work fine:

[image]